# Xamarin.IOS and Instruments profiling trouble

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, instruments

I've tried using Instruments to detect memory troubles. I used the following guide to show me how to setup Xamarin->Instruments, http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/instruments_walkthrough/

However, I see that Instruments have changed some in Xcode5, not that it really matters, but some of the button names etc have changed names. Anyway, my problem is that when running Instruments I don't get the "mono code" when selecting a entry in the call stack in instruments (mentioned in step 14 in the guide above). Sometimes i only get assembler/hex (?) references to calls made in the app (probably because instruments failed to match the dsym file), and most of the time I only get names in the call stack as such: "native_to_managed_trampoline_*_*", which shows some obj-c obfuscated code.

So, how on earth can i profile my app in instruments, see the correct call stack, and when i click on the call stack entry, see the c# code in question (just as in the guide) ??

Answer (score 7):

A few things to check:

- Profile on device, not the simulator. On device you should get symbols for managed frames, while in the simulator you will not (this is because in the simulator the code is jitted, and the information to translate from memory addresses to method names is only present in the process' memory).
- Make sure the app name (foo.app) is the same as your executable name (foo.exe), for some reason symbolication may not work properly otherwise. You can check/modify the executable name in the project's Build/Output options (the 'Assembly Name' field).
- Don't rebuild your app, and then profile an earlier build. Rebuilding will overwrite the dSYM directory, and make it incompatible with any previous builds.
- If you're profiling a Release build, make sure the C# compiler emits debugging information (in the project's Build/Compiler options, set 'Debug information' to 'Full'). This will not impact the final app in any way, it will only make the dSYM directory contain more debugging information (file name / line numbers), so it's safe to leave this option on for your releases too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already profiling on the device. The *.app and *.exe share the same name. Didnt know the third step, but i just checked and it didnt help my in my case. I am currently building for Debug. Any more ideas? :) Thanks again!

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how would i check that? I see that the messages to the console when the app crashed looks ok. and the Device Logs -> Some Crash log shows a bunch of objc type stuff like so: 17  MyApp                       0x00b65d98 native_to_managed_trampoline_MyApp_LoginDialog_ViewWillAppear (registrar.m:2504)

Comment: The crash reports from Device Logs should have fully symbolicated stack traces, something like this: `MyApp 0xaabbccdd MyApp:Main (Main.cs:123)`.

Comment: Yea doesnt seem like they have that. I tried setting up a new project just to see if I got the same results, and it was the same as in my main project. Not symbolicated. I'm a bit at a loss at the moment, I really need to find some leaks in my app.

Comment: Can you pastebin the crash report from the new test project?

Comment: Fresh new project, where i tried to set text to a null UILabel. http://pastebin.com/NTT6xEPC

Comment: You didn't get file name and line number, but you still got the function name: "47  SLETTMEG 0x0002c144 SLETTMEG.Application:Main + 168" - can you pastebin one of your real crash reports? If you don't want it public, you can create a private bug report only Xamarin employees can see (http://bugzilla.xamarin.com), and attach the crash report there.

Comment: Just added a private bug report. With the forementioned crash report. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15812

Comment: Did you find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: No, no solution and the bug report is still open and ongoing.

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge: About: *Profile on device, not the simulator*. Quote from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYourApp/MemoryManagementforYourApp.html): *The Zombies template causes memory growth because it changes your environment so that the zombies are never deallocated. Therefore, for iOS apps, use the **Zombies template with the iOS Simulator** rather than on the device itself. For the same reason, don’t use the Zombies template concurrently with the Leaks instrument.*

Comment: Also, see this for instructions on how to manually associate the appropriate dSYM file with the app being profiled in Instruments.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/Instruments_help_articles/RestoringSymbolsWhenTraceShowsOnlyAddresses/RestoringSymbolsWhenTraceShowsOnlyAddresses.html