# MonoTouch and XCode Instruments - missing source mapping

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin, instruments

Has anyone luck to get a MonoTouch application profiled with the latest XCode instruments? I have followed the instructions of Rolf Bjarne Kvinge (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19658787/271150), so I am running the profiling in debug mode on my device with full debug information provided.

I am able to run Instruments, but I don't get any source mapping. Any hints?

(I am running Xamarin Studio 4.2.2 and Xamarin.iOS 7.0.4.209.)

Comment: Exactly what do you get? Could you also try to create a crash and see if the crash report is symbolicated properly?

Comment: I just threw an NotImplementedException on a buttons touch handler, but there is nothing to see of it in the crash report on the device. I just get a hint of the source where the exception has been thrown, but not the exception itself nor the line number.

Comment: Can you pastebin the entire crash report?

Comment: Sure, here we go: http://pastebin.com/vG18URdg - the "real exception" is as follows (if catched and serialized): http://pastebin.com/y8jgSSYF

Comment: Looks like you're hitting a known bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15202

Comment: Already the second really annoying and serious bugs in the last months  I am facing :-(. Thanks for the info.